# Execute a Command on a Remote Server That Requires Sudo with password input - Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sudo, paramiko

I am trying to execute a sudo command on a remote machine using python-paramiko, (Python 2.7.9 on linux2)
Below is the code. when I execute the code it's giving different output each time, whereas its working fine when I run the same code in python>>> cmdline

```
import paramiko
import sys
import time
def send_string_and_wait(command, wait_time, should_print):
   shell.send(command)
   time.sleep(wait_time)
   receive_buffer = shell.recv(1024)
   if should_print:
     return  receive_buffer

dbname='test'
cl='testdb'
host='testhost'
owner='uname'
passwd='p'


client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(str(host), username=str(owner),  password=str(passwd), port=22)
shell = client.invoke_shell()
send_string_and_wait("sudo su - oracle\n", 1, True)
send_string_and_wait(str(passwd) + "\n", 1, True)
a=send_string_and_wait("sh Validation_Final.sh" + str(' ') +  str(dbname) + str(' ') + str(cl) + "\n", 0, True)
print a
client.close()
```

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2omj.png)

Any advise and suggestions will be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few years ago I have had similar issues, and it turns out that there might be a few reasons for that.

One possible option is that the call waits to get a shell prompt in order to return. However, in the case of a command that requires `sudo`, the behavior might change: In some cases, it will require you to enter the password first. In other cases (e.g., if you have just used `sudo` and it was not timed out yet), it will not require the password again. This inconsistency might cause problems.

Take a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/83960/make-sudo-ask-for-my-password-again) - using `-k` might solve your problem.

In order to solve that, you have to define (if possible) that `sudo` will always require a password, thus make it consistent.

Another issue that might raise is the definition of the shell prompt (some shells use `>`, others use `$`); the same might be true for the `sudo` - it might print `Password:`, which contains no shell prompt and might not be recognized by the remote-command agent, and it might print something else, e.g. `password`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried with sudo -k but no luck. Interestingly it's working when I hard-code dbname and client values like ["""send_string_and_wait('sh /orashare/ettool/Validation_Final.sh dbname client' + "\n", 1, True)"""]

Comment: But I'm facing the issue when passing the variables ""send_string_and_wait("sh /orashare/ettool/Validation_Final.sh" + " " +  str(dbname) + " " + str(cl) + "\n", 0, True)"""  I guess it must be the syntax issue, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Try to see what exactly you get from the remote server. Using `-k` only makes sure that the remote server behaves in a consistent way. However, you must remember that when asking for the password, it uses no shell sign (like `>` or `$`), hence if the paramiko is only waiting for one of those, it will block. You must configure it to refer `Password: ` (or whatever it appears in your system) is considered a shell sign for that call.

Comment: Finally I've solved the issue by changing wait_time argument to 5 seconds  i.e. [ a=send_string_and_wait("sh Validation_Final.sh" + str(' ') +  str(dbname) + str(' ') + str(cl) + "\n", 5, True) ] it's taking 3 to 4 secs to execute the code